# .net Entity framework eager loading with custom Id association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

New to C#.ne. How to do eager loading if the Foreign Id doesn't match the class name?
I saw this example in the official doc.

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs
                    .Include(b => b.Posts)
                    .ToList();
```

I believe under the hood, this one does something like

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Post ON Blog.Id = Post.BlogId
```

In my case, my blog in DB doesn't use `id` as the primary key, it uses `blog_id` and the `post` may use `p_id` as the primary key and `b_id` as the foreign key.

How to customize the `include` with the unconventional key?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to customize this Entity framework will handle this by Navigation properties (provide a way to navigate an association between two entity type) you have in your model (recommended as they map to foreign keys in the database).

The SQL statement generated from the above LINQ statement may look like this as per your schema:

```
SELECT * FROM Blog JOIN Post ON Blog.Blog_Id = Post.B_Id
```